# Check if object is an Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using RxJS 5 and have this method:

```
Queue.prototype.drain = function (obs, opts) {};
```

in the method, I would like to check if the user passed in an `Observable` for the first argument or if they omitted the `Observable` and just passed in an options object.

So basically I need to do something like this:

```
if(!Rx.Observable.isObservable(obs)){  //this method is fictitious
    opts = obs || {};
    obs = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
}
```

I assume RxJS provides users with this kind of check but I cannot find the documentation that shows you how to do this type checking.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Since writing this answer, RxJS version 6 has been released and, in that version, an [`isObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/src/internal/util/isObservable.ts) function was added to the public API. It can be imported like this:

```js
import { isObservable } from "rxjs";
```

The function signature is:

```js
export function isObservable<T>(obj: any): obj is Observable<T>
```

Since it is defined with a typeguard, the compiler can help you out like this:

```js
const result: any = ...;

if (isObservable(result)) 
{
   result.pipe(...);   // compiler now knows it's an observable.
}
```

---

Internally, RxJS tests for an `Observable` [using `instanceof`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.2/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L27):

```js
if (result instanceof Observable) {
  ...
}
```

So you could use:

```js
if (!(obs instanceof Rx.Observable)) {
  opts = obs || {};
  obs = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
}
```

---

`instanceof` can be used to determine whether or not an object is an `Observable` from the RxJS library that you happen to be using.

To determine if the object is a foreign observable, you can [look for a `Symbol.observable` property](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.2/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L70-L77).

If the property is present and is a function, you can obtain an RxJS `Observable` from the foreign observable by passing the value returned by calling the object's `Symbol.observable` property to `Rx.Observable.from`.

Comment: if (isObservable(obj)) { console.log("observable") }

Comment: I hear the `instanceof` operator can break when comparing code running across iframes or what not, makes sense if the constructor function refs aren't the exact same. I assume the implementation of `isObservable` handles that.

Comment: the `!!obj && ` is probably not necessary, can just do `obj &&`

Comment: The only `!!` on this page is in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that checking the key property in the object is still an approach for checking if it is observable.

Here is [an example used in the Nest.js Framework](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/64d072d8bbff552b63332ea12261148b567edd62/packages/microservices/server/server.ts#L50).

Although, there is exactly [a type guard-like util function defined](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/66d8570ea80f85f6a82673b2e802cbef7805aaa9/src/internal/util/isObservable.ts) in official rxjs project currently. It is still seemed to be used internally because I don't see direct export on this function into main index currently.